# Aggregate rows to create new columns based off row content in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I currently have a query that returns this result:

```
|product|status|
|-------|------|
|string1|A     |
|string1|C     |
|string2|B     |
|string2|A     |
|string3|B     |
|string3|B     |
----------------
```

And I would like to be able to convert it into a descriptive table like this.

```
|product|total |A    |B    |C     |
|-------|------|-----|-----|------|
|string1|2     |1    |0    |1     |
|string2|2     |1    |1    |0     |
|string3|2     |0    |2    |0     |
-----------------------------------
```

Is there some kind of rollup or handy function that lets me aggregate rows like this?

Comment: You can't make an SQL query that creates new columns based on the data it finds. Columns must be named explicitly in your query at the time you prepare it (i.e. before it reads any data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pivot the data.  I would recommend conditional aggregation:

```
select product, count(*) as total,
       sum( status = 'A' ) as A,
       sum( status = 'B' ) as B,
       sum( status = 'C' ) as C
from (<your query here>) q
group by product;
```

Comment: Sorry for initially saying this was incorrect, I was using count(status = 'A') earlier in my implementation. When I used sum it worked out.

Answer (score -1):

In redshift and postgresql one should use

```
select product, count(*) as total,
       count(CASE WHEN status = 'A' THEN 1 END) as A,
       count(CASE WHEN status = 'B' THEN 1 END) as B,
       count(CASE WHEN status = 'C' THEN 1 END) as C
from (<your query here>) q
group by product;
```

Comment: I just noticed the question is on mysql ! Feel free to remove if you think it is not relevant to the question.